# Django Relationship Name Collisions - Abstract Model has multiple relationships with another Model

Tags: django, database-design

My application consists of three `Models`: `Users`, `Topics`, and `Responses`.

Each `Response` may either be addressed at a `Topic`, or at another `Response`, but are largely identical. In the interest of not duplicating code, I thought it best to make an abstract model, `Response`, which `ResponseResponse` and `TopicResponse` inherit from.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models           import (CASCADE, CharField, DateTimeField,
                                        ForeignKey, ManyToManyField, Model,
                                        TextField)

class Topic(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 100)

class Response(Model):
    body    = TextField()
    topics  = ManyToManyField(Topic)
    agreers = ManyToManyField(User)

    proposal = TextField()
    affirms  = ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'affirmers')
    rejects  = ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'rejectors')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TopicResponse(Response):
    responseTo = ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = CASCADE)

class ResponseResponse(Response):
    responseTo = ForeignKey(Response, on_delete = CASCADE)
```

The issue with this is that the `User` has two conflicting relationships called `affirmers` and two called `rejectors`.

If I don't give them related names, then instead `TopicResponse` and `ResponseResponse` each have three conflicting relationships, all of them called `TopicResponse` or `ResponseResponse`, respectively, (one for `agreers`, one for `affirms`, one for `rejects`).

An example error message is:

```
app.TopicResponse.rejects: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'TopicResponse.rejects' clashes with reverse query name for 'ResponseResponse.rejects'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TopicResponse.rejects' or 'ResponseResponse.rejects'.
```

If I leave off the `related_name` argument, I get error messages like this:

```
app.ResponseResponse.rejects: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ResponseResponse.rejects' clashes with reverse accessor for 'ResponseResponse.affirms'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ResponseResponse.rejects' or 'ResponseResponse.affirms'.
```

What can I do to fix all of these conflicts? I need to somehow have the `related_name` dynamically generated with the name of the of the concrete instance of the Model (like it is if you don't specify it) plus the name of the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the related name unique. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name) you can add `%(class)s` or `%(app_label)s`. These are then replaced by the child class values:

```
class Topic(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 100)

    class Response(Model):
        body    = TextField()
        topics  = ManyToManyField(Topic)
        agreers = ManyToManyField(User)

        proposal = TextField()
        affirms  = ManyToManyField(User, related_name = '%(app_label)s_%(class)saffirmers')
        rejects  = ManyToManyField(User, related_name = '%(app_label)s_%(class)srejectors')

        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    class TopicResponse(Response):
        responseTo = ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = CASCADE)

    class ResponseResponse(Response):
        responseTo = ForeignKey(Response, on_delete = CASCADE)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! This looks like it should work - I'll come back and accept your answer once I've verified it does tonight.